# A problem with using two different bibliography styles on Ubuntu

Tags: bibtex

I use Latex with kile 2.1 on Ubuntu. I do not understand why when using `\bibliographystyle{plain}` it works very well, whereas when I use `\bibliographystyle{apsrev}` it doesn't (`[?]` are printed everywhere).

Could you give me some advice?

Additionally, there is no problem with WinEdit on Windows XP.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.aux` files and running latex bibtex latex latex again?

Comment: Do you have the apsrev.bst file in your project folder or somewhere where latex can find it?

Answer (score 3):

The `revtex4` package contains `apsrev.bst`. On Ubuntu, install the package `texlive-publishers` using Synaptic or apt-get, it contains Revtex.

Comment: Many thanks for every answers. I have tried to do as the answers, but the problem is still unsolved.

Comment: @Paad: in a terminal, run `kpsewhich apsrev.bst`. The output indicates the route of the file; if you get no output, then the files is not installed in your system. Please report the output obtained.

Comment: I got no output. But I had installed texlive-publishers_2009-7ubuntu3_all.deb already.